# PartnerException = Access Denied while uploading Manifest on Azure AD application pool

Tags: office365, office365-apps, office365-restapi

My admin have rights as user management & exchange but when we are trying to upload a manifest file we are getting below error. We are trying to create daemon service an application as mentioned [Here] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/building-service-apps-in-office-365).

Error:

PartnerException=Access Denied.; PartnerServiceException=You don’t have permission to access this page or perform this action.; DataServiceQueryException=An error occurred while processing this request.; DataServiceClientException={"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"This operation can only be performed by an administrator. Sign out and sign in as an administrator or contact one of your organization's administrators."}}};

Can you provide details about this error? Do we need to provide any more permission to admin users?

Comment: have you tried to login using a private browser window? it seems the portal is caching a different profile that is not an admin.

Comment: Hi Mostafa, we tried it on private browsing but we are getting same error. We have given **bold ** User Management Administrator & Exchange Administrator rights. but apart from that do we need service administrator rights as well?

Comment: Any updates on rights is really appriciated

Comment: I'm having the same issue, any update on this?